# Within Looping Make Summary Table by filling data based on conditional

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, dplyr

Lets say I have looping and in each looping there is a table result like this:

```
  #Looping Result Data
  value <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
  value.dat <- rep("Yes", 4)
  n <- c(4, 1, 2, 4 )
  resloop <- data.frame(value, value.dat, n)
```

Within the loop I want to have (in the end) summary table for every loop and the table looks like this:

```
Country <- rep(c("Germany", "France"), each=12)
Sectoral <- rep(c("A-A", "B-A", "B-B", "A-C", "C-B", "C-C"), times=4)
Connection <- rep(c("Yes", "No"), each=6)
Freq.Ind <- NA
t.sum<- data.frame(Country, Sectoral, Connection, Freq.Ind)
```

Freq.Ind should be filled by the value from resloop which has the most n (so can be more than one value if there are same big n)

So if now in the loop:

```
 i<-"Germany"
 j<-"A-A"
```

I want in the Freq.Ind first row fill with:  A1, A4

I have tried something like this, but something still wrong :( (newbie)

```
 t.sum[t.sum$Country == i && t.sum$Sectoral == j && t.sum$Connection ==  "Yes", "Freq.Ind"]<- as.character(resloop$value[resloop$n==max(resloop$n)])
t.sum$Freq.Ind <- ifelse( t.sum$Country == i & t.sum$Sectoral == j & t.sum$Connection == "Yes",  as.character(resloop$value[resloop$n==max(resloop$n)]), next )


 t.sum %>% 
     mutate(Freq.Ind=replace(Freq.Ind, Country == i & Sectoral == j &  Connection == "Yes" ,as.character(resloop$value[resloop$n==max(resloop$n)])))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I have got this from trial (so far)

```
as.character(resloop$value[resloop$n==max(resloop$n)])-> themax
themax <- cbind(themax)
library(stringr)
str_c(themax, collapse = ",") ->themax

t.sum %>% 
mutate(Freq.Ind=replace(Freq.Ind, Country == i & Sectoral == j & Connection == "Yes" ,themax))
```

Im sure there are more simple way, feel free to share.